# What is the integer format in memory?

Tags: javascript, integer

I just started reading Javascript (Professional JavaScript for Web Developers, 3rd Edition) and the text variously says that integers are:

```
[1] Stored as IEEE-754 format (pg. 35).
[2] Have a -0 value (pg. 36).
[3] Stored as a 32-bit two's complement number (pg. 50).
[4] Stored as a IEEE-754 64-bits number (pg. 49).
```

These are inconsistent definitions. What is the format of an integer in Javascipt?

thanks

Comment: There are no integers in JavaScript, every number is a double. Except when it comes to bitwise operation, for whom they are casted to ints (that's what page 50 likely refers to) and then back to doubles.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the specification:

http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5

According to the specification, javascript doesn't have integers, only floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

IEEE-754 floats do have a -0 value, so there's no inconsistency between 1, 2 and 4. Only 3 appears to be inconsistent.

Javascript numbers are always *stored* as IEEE-754 64-bit floating point numbers. In some expressions (usually with bitwise operators) they may be temporarily *converted* to 32-bit integers and then converted back to 64-bit floats, but they're always stored as floats. I assume this conversion is what #3 is actually referring to.

A JIT compiler for Javascript may use actual integers in the compiled code as an optimization (especially if asm.js is involved), but during interpretation it's still all floats.